# Recursive function: for vs if

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

In one of the C exercises I had to create a function for binary tree traversal with a given depth.

My first thought was to use a for loop (`traverse_preorder_bad`). Finally, I could complete the task with a variable initialization + `if` (`traverse_preorder_working`), but I am still struggling to understand why the `for` solution didn't work.

Could someone explain me the difference? Is there an elegant solution?

[Code on Ideone](http://ideone.com/qNedRl)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

const int RANGE = 1000;

typedef struct node_t
{
    int data;
    struct node_t *left;
    struct node_t *right;
} node_t;

node_t *node_new(int data);
node_t *node_insert(node_t *tree, int data);
void traverse_preorder_working(node_t *tree, int depth);
void traverse_preorder_bad(node_t *tree, int depth);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    node_t *tree = NULL;

    // Random seed
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));

    // Create the root node
    tree = node_new(rand() % RANGE);

    node_insert(tree, 5);
    node_insert(tree, 1);

    printf("Expected output:\n");
    traverse_preorder_working(tree, 10);

    printf("Bad output:\n");
    traverse_preorder_bad(tree, 10);

    return 0;
}

node_t *node_new(int data)
{
    node_t *tree;

    tree = malloc(sizeof(*tree));
    tree->left = NULL;
    tree->right = NULL;
    tree->data = data;

    return tree;
}

node_t *node_insert(node_t *tree, int data)
{
    if (!tree)
        return node_new(data);

    if (data == tree->data)
        return tree;
    if (data < tree->data)
        tree->left = node_insert(tree->left, data);
    else
        tree->right = node_insert(tree->right, data);

    return tree;
}

void traverse_preorder_working(node_t *tree, int depth)
{
    int i;

    if (!tree)
        return;

    printf("%d\n", tree->data);

    i = 1;
    if (tree->left && i <= depth)
    {
        traverse_preorder_working(tree->left, depth - i);
        i++;
    }

    i = 1;
    if (tree->right && i <= depth)
    {
        traverse_preorder_working(tree->right, depth - i);
        i++;
    }
}

void traverse_preorder_bad(node_t *tree, int depth)
{
    if (!tree)
        return;

    printf("%d\n", tree->data);

    for (int i = 1; tree->left && i <= depth; i++)
        traverse_preorder_bad(tree->left, depth - i);

    for (int i = 1; tree->right && i <= depth; i++)
        traverse_preorder_bad(tree->right, depth - i);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by elegant? Recursion is absolutely elegant. The main problem with recursion is the memory/time requirement for the call activation frames but, apart from that, recursion is totally elegant.

Comment: @Jack, recursion is great! I just don't like how my solution looks like. Having to set a helper variable twice, taking a whole lot of lines for a simple thing...

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `traverse_preorder_working` is correctly recursive, when visiting a node you call `traverse_preorder_working` recursively on the left subtree (and then right)

Instead `traverse_preorder_bad` is still recursive but it makes no sense, when you visit a node you then call `traverse_preorder_bad` n-times on the same subtree with a different depth.

If you check invocation tree for something like:

```
       a
      / \
     b   c
    / \ / \
    d e f g
```

You can see that `traverse_preorder_working(a,5)` goes `traverse_preorder_working(b,4)`, `traverse_preorder_working(d,3)` .. while other function goes

```
traverse_preorder_bad(a,5),
traverse_preorder_bad(b,4), visit subtree
traverse_preorder_bad(b,3), visit subtree
traverse_preorder_bad(b,2), visit subtree
traverse_preorder_bad(b,1), visit subtree ...
```

from the same level of recursion, which means that each node will be visited multiple times with different depth limits; this doesn't happen in the first correct version.

If each invocation of `traverse_preorder_bad` should visit a node and start visiting both subtrees **but inside the code you call visit recursively more than twice** (which is the case, since you have a loop) **then something is wrong**.

Answer (score 2):

The "for" version make no sense. You only want to print the tree for a given node once, so you should only call traverse on each node once.

Additionally, based on one of your comments in your post, I think you have some misunderstandings about your working function.

You have multiple checks for whether the tree is null (both as the current tree or as its children)

`i` ever only has a value of one while it is being used. You could simplify to

```
void traverse_preorder_working(node_t *tree, int depth){
    if(!tree || depth <= 0){
        return;
    }
    printf("%d\n", tree->data);
    traverse_preorder_working(tree->left, depth - 1);
    traverse_preorder_working(tree->right, depth - 1);
}
```

All of the checks to see if we not should explore a node - either because it doesn't exist or it is too deep - are done only once (at the start of the function), and not repeated twice for each child. No `i` variable that does nothing.

Comment: Now, that's elegant. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The elegant solution here (without recursion) is Morris Traversal. The idea is to add indirection edge from the left subtree's rightmost node to the current node.

The full explanation of the algorithm is here: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/inorder-tree-traversal-without-recursion-and-without-stack/

Of course you can modify this algorithm not to go deeper then you current depth.

Comment: I think this algorithm is simply wrong, OP didn't try to be smarter than just correct

Comment: No, you can evaluate this algorithm by your hands. It's also well known algorithm, just google.